# C++ function switch statement or array abstract over macro values

Tags: c++, templates, macros

Consider the following code:

```
#define VAL_A 0
#define VAL_B 1
#define VAL_C 2

void TestSwitch01(uint32 val)
{
    printf("%u: ", op);
    switch (val)
    {
    case VAL_A: printf("aaa\n"); break;
    case VAL_B: printf("bbb\n"); break;
    case VAL_C: printf("ccc\n"); break;
    default: printf("ddd\n");
    }
}

#define VAL_A 10
#define VAL_B 11
#define VAL_C 12

void TestSwitch02(uint32 op)
{
    printf("%u: ", op);
    switch (val)
    {
    case VAL_A: printf("aaa\n"); break;
    case VAL_B: printf("bbb\n"); break;
    case VAL_C: printf("ccc\n"); break;
    default: printf("ddd\n");
    }
}
```

In this example, I have three `VAL_*` macros and two `TestSwitch*()` functions.  However, suppose I have this pattern but with 5000 `VAL_*` macros and 20 `TestSwitch*()` functions (in other words - 20 different versions of `VAL_A` - 0, 10, etc).  Also, I have the `#define`'s in separate files...  So `foo001.h` has the (0 1 2) `VAL`'s and `foo002.h` has the (10 11 12) `VAL`'s.

I don't want to copy-paste 20 versions of the function because it's the same function.  So really I want to write a function that abstracts over the macro.

Obviously I could use variables, but I don't want to do that because the variables would be set at run-time and that would be slow.  I want write C++ code that will get the compiler to generate 20 versions of `TestSwitch*()` each corresponding to one of the 20 different sets of 5000 `VAL*` macros.

I want to avoid writing a macro pseudo-function because you can't step into that, plus it's hard to read (also syntax highlighting and intellisense won't work).

I considered using a template function, but with 5000 `VAL_*` macros, it would be pretty insane...  `template void <uint32 VAL_A, uint32 VAL_B ... VAL_4999> TestSwitch(...)`.

I also tried to do it by replacing the `switch()` statements with arrays of function pointers (to the `printf()`'s)...  But then I still had the copy-paste code problem when filling the arrays.

I feel like C++ has the tools to do what I'm trying to do, but I'm not sure how...  Any ideas?

Basically I want to generate 20 copies of function `TestSwitchXX()` - one for each set of 5000 `VAL_*`'s.

Maybe there's some trick using multiple files and `#include`'s and `#if`'s?

Comment: C++ is not a swiss army knife. It can't do everything. If this is truly what you want (and I kind of see why you'd want it), and all the values of switch statements have some logical pattern to them, then use the right tool for the right job: write a simple Perl script, or using a scripting language of your choice to robo-generate all of your spaghetti code, and integrate it into your build system. If that's good enough for `lex/flex` and `yacc/bison`, it's good enough here.

Comment: use concatenation operator

Comment: Lookup tables.  Design a structure that contains the key and a pointer to a function that processes the key.  Place into a map or vector.  Search for the key then if the key is found, execute the *associated* function by dereferencing the function pointer.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews This is exactly what my OP means by the following comment...  I also tried to do it by replacing the switch() statements with arrays of function pointers (to the printf()'s)... But then I still had the copy-paste code problem when filling the arrays...  Instead of TestSwitch01() TestSwitch02() etc, I end up needing FillArray01() FillArray02() etc

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik that's actually my best idea so far and it's what I'm currently doing for the old version of my code...  However, I'm still wondering if there's some way to do it in actual C++ code (rather than generating C++ code with Perl or Python).  I thought there might be some trick like #include foo001.h, then forward declare template void TestSwitch<1>(), then #include foo2.h then forward declare template void TestSwitch<2>() though I couldnt get that to compile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A properly C++ solution for this would be to do away with the `#define`s and use enums within structs:

```
struct Foo {
    enum { VAL_A = 0, VAL_B = 1, VAL_C = 2 };
};

struct Bar {
    enum { VAL_A = 10, VAL_B = 11, VAL_C = 12 };
};

template<typename T>
void TestSwitch(int op)
{
    std::cout << op << ": ";
    switch (op) {
        case T::VAL_A: std::cout << "aaa\n"; break;
        case T::VAL_B: std::cout << "bbb\n"; break;
        case T::VAL_C: std::cout << "ccc\n"; break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/u3kTtF

You could also replace the `struct` with just an `enum class` but then you can only have values, the struct option gives you the chance to include other values that describe things about `T` that might later be useful.

enum class Demo: http://ideone.com/DBZuyn

Comment: This is my favorite answer so far.  I'd probably write a python script to convert my #define header files to enum's

Answer (score 0):

[XMacros](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387) - they were trending... let me see... yeap, 2001.

On the line of:

"generate_testswitch.h"

```
#define IMPLEMENT_TEST_SWITCH(N) void TestSwitch#N(uint32 val) \
{ \
    printf("%u: ", op); \
    switch (val) \
    { \
    case VAL_A: printf("aaa\n"); break; \
    case VAL_B: printf("bbb\n"); break; \
    case VAL_C: printf("ccc\n"); break; \
    default: printf("ddd\n"); \
    } \
}
```

"testswitch1.c"

```
// you may isolate these in yet another header
#define VAL_A 0
#define VAL_B 1
#define VAL_C 2

#include "generate_testswitch.h"

IMPLEMENT_TEST_SWITCH(01)
```

Comment: That's exactly what my OP means by "macro pseudo-function"...  I want to avoid writing a macro pseudo-function because you can't step into that (with a debugger), plus it's hard to read (also syntax highlighting and intellisense won't work).  The \'s at the end of each line are weird syntax but more importantly Visual Studio (and I assume gdb) lack support for debugging these or doing proper intellisense and syntax highlighting I guess because macros are preprocessor string-replace rather than "real" C++ code.

Comment: @pemcode "more importantly Visual Studio (and I assume gdb) lack support for debugging these". You know, utilities generating code that compiles afterwars aren't so an outlandish idea. So, I suppose that you can write a C++ utility which read those "#define VAL_A" headers and then dumps them packed as a function definition in a file called "my_func_X.cpp".

Answer (score 0):

> I considered using a template function, but with 5000 `VAL_*` macros, it would be pretty insane... `template void <uint32 VAL_A, uint32 VAL_B ... VAL_4999> TestSwitch(...)`.

For you tagged the question as `c++`, I assume the latest revision of the standard can be used (or at least C++11).
Because of that, no, it wouldn't be pretty insane to use a template.
You can do something like this with variadic templates:

```
template<typename T, T... V>
void TestSwitch(uint32_t val) {
    // ...
}
```

Thus you can invoke it as:

```
TestSwitch<int, 10, 11, 12>(42);
```

I've not clear what you want to do with those values, so it's hard to say how the body of the function must be written.
As a toy example, it follows an implementation that checks if `val` is contained in `V...`:

```
template<typename T, T... V>
void TestSwitch(uint32_t val) {
    bool found = false;
    int arr[] = { 0, (found = found || (val == V), 0 )... };
    (void)arr;
    std::cout << "found: " << found << std::endl;
}
```

Other problems could require a recursion with an empty case and so on.

---

As long as you deal with ranges, you can also do something like this:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t B, std::size_t... I>
void TestSwitch(uint32_t val, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    bool found = false;
    int arr[] = { 0, (found = found || (val == (B+I)), 0 )... };
    (void)arr;
    std::cout << "found: " << found << std::endl;
}

template<std::size_t B, std::size_t N>
void TestSwitch(uint32_t val) {
    TestSwitch<B>(val, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main() {
    TestSwitch<40, 3>(42);
    TestSwitch<40, 3>(0);
}
```

In this case, we invoke `TestSwitch` using the *base* (that is, the start value) and the length of the range, then we rely on `std::make_index_sequence` and one more function to generate the range itself and do the work.

Comment: there are 5000 of the values, so even with variadic templates, it would be pretty insane calling

TestSwitch<int, 10, 11, 12, ...>(42) where the ... is (5000-3 = 4997) integers typed out - it's very long and cumbersome.  In my real example there's 20x20 = 400 versions of TestSwitch(), so I'd have 400 of these template calls with 5000 template parameters to each one.  At that point I might as well just do the copy-paste method which I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: I'm hoping there's a way that I can #include my two #define macro files that define different versions of 5000 #define VAL_*'s...  And use this to generate two separate TestSwitch() functions.  Otherwise I have to copy-paste TestSwitch() as TestSwitch001() using #include foo001.h's #defines, and then and TestSwitch002() which is an exact copy-paste of TestSwitch001() code except that it's in a different file that #include's foo002.h.

Comment: @pemcode Added more details to the answer. You don't have to explicitly define all the 5000 values if they represent a range. Let me know if it works fine for you.

Comment: The simplified example in my OP uses a range, but the values in my actual header files (which come from a third party) do not include a range.